# My boss never made my fill out a w4 but pays me in checks. Will I end up having to pay taxes if he claims I work for him?

Tags: united-states, taxes

I’m 19 and started working for a guy in May of this year. He never gave me a w4, but paid me in cash for a couple weeks then started paying me in checks. He then said a few weeks ago that even though I didn’t sign a w4 that he says he showed me that I will end up paying taxes so he doesn’t have to. Will I have to pay taxes? How will this end? And if I leave in the middle of September will I be exempt from paying any taxes since I wouldn’t have worked for very long?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129152/discussion-on-question-by-sebatian-baker-my-boss-never-made-my-fill-out-a-w4-but).

Answer (score 15):

Regardless of a Form W-4 or not, regardless of whether your employer withholds taxes or not, you are still responsible for any income taxes that may be due as a result of your income.

Now depending on how much you make during the year, you may or may not owe taxes since those in lower income brackets may be exempt from income tax but you will still need to file the proper forms.

If your employer was required to withhold and pay the IRS and did not then they may have some liability but it doesn't relieve you of paying any taxes owed by you.

You can start with an online IRS resource such as this one:

[IRS Tax Calculator](https://apps.irs.gov/app/tax-withholding-estimator/income-and-withholding)

To estimate your tax liability based on what you have made and expect to make through the rest of this year.

Note that depending on your State, that State and even local taxes may also be due and you'll want to check with your State's tax authority as well.

Comment: Also note that if your employer is not withholding taxes for you, you may be responsible for paying estimated taxes into the IRS on a quarterly basis. There can be stiff penalties if the amount of tax you owe is a lot more than what you have withheld at filing time (April). Here's some more information on that: https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/estimated-taxes

Answer (score 2):

> Will I have to pay taxes?

**Yes.**  You will also have to pay into social security, unemployment and several other program which normally come out of your check.

> And if I leave in the middle of September will I be exempt from paying any taxes since I wouldn’t have worked for very long?

You've worked for him since May, that's 5 months.  That's a long time according to the IRS.  Be prepared to at least pay for an accountant when you file your taxes.  You may be able to get some basic legal help from LegalZoom without breaking the bank.

Comment: This should be voted much higher up.  The problem isn't just income tax, its employment tax.  If he isn't paying your employment tax, then you're going to be legally liable for it, as it looks like you're an independent business (and running an independent business you pay self employment tax).  What you're doing is called working under the table, and its illegal on his part and risky on yours.

Comment: @GabeSechan, No, paying someone with checks and telling them to declare it to the IRS does NOT mean that he's "working under the table". See definition: https://www.taxsharkinc.com/working-under-the-table/  "and its illegal on his part" Not necessarily. For instance, if the OP cut his lawn and did yard work on the OP's own schedule using the OP's own tools, it's perfectly legal that he be considered an independent contractor. The fact is. The OP simply hasn't provided enough details about the kind of job this was, and how it was performed.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk He's being paid in checks and not having taxes paid.  If you think he isn't being paid under the table, you're in fantasy land.  As for independent contractor-  he definitely doesn't think he's one from his post, he thinks he's an employee.

Comment: @GabeSechan, What are you even talking about? I've been paid the same way. And I've been making my quarterly payments and I've been filing my schedule C tax form. Are you saying that I've been doing it wrong all these years? And no where does he say in his post that he's an employee. If anything, based on the lack of a W4, and everything that was said to him, it's pretty clear that he understands that he may be liable for extra taxes.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk Given that he seemed to be expecting to not pay taxes (other than possibly income), there is no way in hell he thought he was anything other than an employee.  You're giving him way too much credit, based on him posting this its obvious he doesn't know what an employee is, what a contractor is, or which he was.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk Remember this is a 19 year old kid, likely on his first job.  You're crediting him for sophistication of finances that most adults don't understand the nuances of.  And the fact he needed to post this is sufficient proof he definitely doesn't.

Comment: @GabeSechan, "Remember this is a 19 year old kid" This is precisely why you want to make sure the information you're giving him is correct. Or at least, communicate some doubts in some of your assumptions. Because saying something like this "What you're doing is called working under the table, and its illegal on his part..." is just a bad idea. It's a speculation that is stated with so much conviction, that 19 year old kid might actually think that you're correct on that point.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk Because I am correct on that point.  The employer hasn't paid any of his taxes. Most likely because he expected to pay him under the table, because 99% of the time when you don't have a contract and pay cash, that's what the deal is.  I find it laughably naive that you expect it to be anything other than that.  Now he *can* pay his self employment and other taxes and avoid illegality-  but he obviously didn't know anything about all that.  Your post is the one that would have done him immense harm if caught.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk FWIW, I think the OP is just completely unknowledgable and confused, rather than attempting tax fraud.  And that's unfortunate, because it's about to force him to decide to either cheat on his taxes or pay an unexpected tax bill that he didn't budget for and may not have the money for.

Comment: @GabeSechan, You've said your peace. I've said mine. Let's just agree to disagree. Good bye.

Answer (score -4):

First thing you should talk to a tax and employment lawyer.

There may be  free ones, but in any way you need to know what you are dealing with.

In Canada, for example, even if you are not considered employee by your "employer", under specific conditions he actually is and required to pay at least employer part of taxes.

Comment: I don't know why all you guys keep telling minimum wage workers to consult a lawyer.  This is not even lawyer worthy.  Download TurboTax and file your taxes.

Comment: @Jack It's just people that are under the mistaken assumption that a lawyer will ALWAYS be worth the hassle. Sometimes they are, but often they are not.

Comment: @Jack Almost every situation can be swept under the rug at some personal cost, large or small. This is exactly why these types of employers exist, because employees ARE NOT AWARE of their rights and unable / unwilling to find them out.